# Set of all positive definite matrices with off diagonal elements negative

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, hessian-matrix

Please, help me to find the set of all positive definite matrices (PDM) of which off diagonal elements are negative.

Considering the case with n=2, the symmetric mat $A=[a_1, a_2;a_2, a_3]$ needs to be a PD. i.e.  $x'Ax>0$,  $a_2\neq 0$, $x\neq 0$ where $x=[x_1,x_2]'$.

Always we have $a_1>0$ and $a_3>0$ as they are principal minors.

I guess such matrices exists as $x_1^2a_1+2x_1x_2a_2+x_2^2a_3$ can be positive with either of $x_1$ or $x_2$ negative and $a_2$ negative.

Also, in case which $x_1>0$, $x_2>0$ and $a_2<0$, the condition $x'Ax>0$ is met if the absolute value of $x_1^2a_1+x_2^2a_3$ is greater than absolute value of $2x_1x_2a_2$.

How can I genearlize this to denote and derive set of all possible positive definite matrices? I mean can you give some examples of A which is positive definite with offdiagonal elements negative?
or suggest  method to get them? please?

Comment: "Always we have $x_1 > 0$ and $x_3 > 0$", 

I guess you meant $a_1$ and $a_3$?

Also I think it is easier to work with the condition 
$$A \text{ is a PDM } \Leftrightarrow \text{ all principial minors are positive},$$
as for the case $n=2$ you simply get $A$ is a PDM iff $a_1a_3 > a_2^2$.

Comment: Thank you chickenNinja....you are right I meant $a_1$ and $a_3$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and comment :)

Comment: I need to derive the condition for a 4x 4 matrix. So the condition is going to be a little involved!

Comment: @chickenNinja123 , can you please suggest a way to show that all such matrices, that is those with off diagonal elements negative but still positive definite form a convex set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all possible values of off-diagonal elements of a matrix A such that A is positive definite and all the off-diagonal elements are negative:

First assume that the diagonal elements are given, $a_{11}, a_{22},a_{33},a_{44}$, which must be positive.  I will presume that by positive definite, you mean symmetric positive definite.  Let the 6 upper triangular elements be variables, a_{12},a_{13},a_{14},a_{23},a_{24},a_{34}. The lower triangle is determined by symmetry.

Using MATLAB notation, you need all principal minors to be positive:
det(A(1:2,1:2)) > 0 , det(A(1:3,1:3)) > 0, det(A) > 0  (note that det(A(1:1,1:1)) = $a_{11}$ which is > 0 by assumption). You can expand these out symbolically, which results in a set of 3 strict inequalities in 6 variables. Additionally. there are negativity constraints on all 6 variables.  The set of all solutions to these 9 inequalities is the solution to your problem.  However, from a practical perspective, this is not a good way to compute things, and really just serves as a theoretical exercise.

As for the question in your comment "can you please suggest a way to show that all such matrices, that is those with off diagonal elements negative but still positive definite form a convex set?":  You should already know that the set of all positive definite matrices is convex (a convex cone).  Any convex combination of negative numbers will be negative, therefore, a convex combination of matrices having negative off-diagonal elements will have negative off-diagonal elements. Hence the set of all matrices having negative off-diagonal elements is convex.  Hence, the set of all positive definite matrices having negative off-diagonal elements is the intersection of two convex sets, hence is convex.

Comment: So you mean to say finding set of all symmetric positive definite matrices $\in\mathbb{R}^5$ with off diagonal elements negative is a tedious job, right?

Comment: Finding all, yes.  But you can use determinant of leading 2 by 2 to bound values of (1,2) element. Lower right-hand 2 by 2  bounds values on (3,4) element.  But finding all values of off-diagonal elements requires all solutions to a system of inequalities, which is very tedious, and may further restrict the (1,2) and (3,4) elements.  Finding one or more symmetric psd matrices with negative elements is easy to do using semidefinite programming.  You can make up an objective you like, add additional constraints, if any, and find a matrix satisfying them.

Comment: Thank you..I still have a doubt.....in case of matrices, we talk about convexity of the space spanned by matrix. is it ok to consider the convex combination of off diagonal elements and say that their intersection gives convex set?Please also note tht the diagonal elements are positive.

Comment: Take 2 matrices having negative off-diagonal elements and positive diagonal elements.. A convex combination of those matrices will have negative off-diagonal elements and positive diagonal elements (it may help you to view it one element at a time). Therefore the set of matrices having negative off-diagonal elements. and positive diagonal elements is convex.

Comment: But in any event, the last paragraph of my answer contains the proof regarding the question you asked, which is regarding positive definite matrices with negative off-diagonal elements (i.e., positive definite, not merely positive diagonal elements).